# How to ignore highlighted fields in a kibana query?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I'm trying to make a query in kibana that shows all the errors in a service, but the results only shows the data with the field "highlight", how can I ignore it?

I've tried making a DSL query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "payload.error"
    }
  }
}
```

but it does not work as I expect

This is the structure of the data that is show in the query answer:

```
 "payload": {
      "method": "standardError",
      "error": {
        "code": "300",
        "detail": "{\"Cliente no posee fecha\"}",
        "message": "BUS_ERROR"
      }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "payload.error.code.keyword": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@107@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ]
  }
```

The data that is not show in the query result does not have the field "highlight" but have the exact same payload structure

I expect a query that shows all the data with the field payload.error, no matter if it has a highlight field or not

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for, but can't you just use the Search Box on the top and write something like:

```
payload.error:* AND highlight.payload.error.code.keyword:
```

That will give you all the hits that fulfill them both. Or:

```
payload.error:*
```

That will give you all the hits where "payload.error" is used.

As I read your example, then highlight doesn't really have anything to do with the first payload, you have above and therefore searching only for "payload.error:*" should be enough?